# sql server multiple columns into one row

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have this table:

```
Reg_No      Student_Name         Subject     Total
----------- -------------------- ----------- -----------
101         Canday               85          347
                                 94           
                                 78           
                                 90           
102         Andy                 75          332
                                 88           
                                 91           
                                 78
```

I want this table

```
Reg_No      Student_Name         Subject1    Subject2    Subject3    Subject4    Total
----------- -------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
101         Canday                85          94          78          90          347
102          Andy                 75          88          91          78          332
```

Comment: look at `PIVOT` command. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: Then modify the table so that it looks as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Consider your table name is `#Temp`. I have written logic inside the query.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    -- Get ROW_NUMBER() in default order of your table
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT(0)))RNO
    FROM #TEMP
)
,CTE2 AS
(
    -- Since we need some logic to get the NULL VALUES for each Id we fill REG_NO where previous REG_NO is not null
    -- Note that Id must be in ascending order in your table as in question
    SELECT RNO, (SELECT TOP 1 Reg_No FROM CTE WHERE RNO<=C1.RNO AND Reg_No IS NOT NULL ORDER BY Reg_No DESC) REGNO,
    Student_Name,[SUBJECT],[TOTAL]  
    FROM CTE C1
)
,CTE3 AS
(
    -- Get all Student_Name and Total where those are NULL
    SELECT N1.RNO,N1.REGNO,
    n1.Student_Name,N2.[Subject],N1.Total
    FROM CTE2 N1
    LEFT JOIN CTE2 N2 ON N1.REGNO=N2.REGNO AND N1.Student_Name IS NOT NULL 
    WHERE n1.Student_Name IS NOT NULL AND N2.[Subject] IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT RNO,REGNO,Student_Name,[Subject],
-- To get columns names for Pivot ie Subject1,Subject2 etc
'Subject' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY REGNO ORDER BY (SELECT(0)))AS VARCHAR(10)) COLS
INTO #NEWTABLE
FROM CTE3
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT RNO,REGNO,Student_Name,[TOTAL],'Total'
FROM CTE3
```

Get the columns for pivoting

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + COLS + ']', 
               '[' + COLS + ']')
               FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT COLS FROM #NEWTABLE) PV  
               ORDER BY COLS
```

Now pivot it

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = '           
              SELECT * FROM 
             (
                 SELECT REGNO REG_NO,Student_Name,[Subject],COLS FROM #NEWTABLE
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 SUM([Subject])
                 FOR [COLS] IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p      
            ORDER BY REG_NO
            '     
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

- **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6ab20/3)**

**RESULT**

[image]